# Dapper. Execute Query with GOs

Tags: sql, dapper

I am trying to use Dapper to run a SQL Query:

```
use master
go

if exists (select name from sys.databases where name = N'TestDB')
drop database [TestDB]
go

create database [TestDB] on primary ( 
  name = 'TestDB_Data',
  filename = '$Path\TestDB_Data.mdf',
  size = 40MB,
  maxsize = 2GB,
  filegrowth = 20MB 
)

use [TestDB]
go

create table dbo.Posts
(
  Id int identity not null,
  Body nvarchar (max) null
);
```

I am using Dapper as follows:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
  connection.Open();
  connection.Execute(sqlQuery);
}
```

However, I get an error when using GO.

But if I remove the GO statements I get an error when creating Posts because the table TestDB wasn't created.

Is there a way to use Dapper to solve this?

I was able to do this only using SQL Server SDK.

Comment: `GO` is not a T-SQL statement, it is a directive only interpreted by certain SQL Server utilities. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dapper cannot help you here. Instead, I would suggest you try SQL Server Management Objects to execute large SQL commands like the one you mentioned. And it does supports GO statements.

You can check out this [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2006/11/07/Handling-_2200_GO_2200_-Separators-in-SQL-Scripts-_2D00_-the-easy-way.aspx) for step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 10):

GO is not a SQL statement it is merely a batch separator, in fact you could rename it to whatever you want.

[image: batch seperator]

The way Management Studio figures this out is by parsing the SQL. It is easy to write a trivial parser that can chunk the statements up. Just split the string on "GO" and send each statement to Dapper.

However, to be 100% correct you need a [sophisticated parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76083/parsing-sql-in-net).

```
select '
GO ' GO from [GO]
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved separating the executions

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            foreach (var item in sqlQuery.Split("GO"))
            {
                conn.Execute(item);
            }
        }
```